# Can I temporarily store a value in the Select Statement of SQL?

Tags: select, store, formula, ssms, temporary-objects

In my select statement, I have two returns that are calculations. It looks like this:

```
 SELECT
     a.FormRate AS 'F-Rate'
     ,a.LoI AS 'Liability'
     ,CAST((A.FormRate * a.LoI / 100) AS DECIMAL(38,2)) 'F-Premium'
     ,a.EndorsementRate AS 'E-Rate'
     ,CAST((A.EndorsementRate * a.LoI / 100) AS DECIMAL(38,2)) 'E-Premium' 

FROM tblAspecs a
```

Once I have those five statements in the select, I'd like to be able to total E-Premium + F-Premium into a new column. I could always do it this way:

```
  ,CAST(((A.EndorsementRate * a.Loi / 100) + (a.FormRate * a.LoI / 100)) AS DECIMAL(38,2)) 'Total Premium'
```

...but that just just seems to be quite sloppy and bulky. Is there a way to store the individual premiums so that I can just do a simple `CAST((F-Premium + E-Premium) AS DECIMAL(38,2)) 'Total Premium'`

The bulky way also doesn't leave F-Premium and E-Premium dynamic so that if I ever change how they're calculated, I'd have to also change the calculation in the Total Premium column.

Using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 2010

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Research [Common Table Expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx).

It will look something like this:

```
;WITH [Data]
(
    [FormRate],
    [Liability],
    [FormPremium],
    [EndorsementRate],
    [EndorsementPremium]
)
AS
(
    SELECT
         a.[FormRate],
         a.[LoI] AS [Liability],
         CAST((a.[FormRate] * a.[LoI] / 100) AS DECIMAL(38,2)),
         a.[EndorsementRate],
         CAST((a.[EndorsementRate] * a.[LoI] / 100) AS DECIMAL(38,2)) 
    FROM 
        tblAspecs a
)
SELECT
    [Data].*,
    CAST(([Data].[FormPremium] + [Data].[EndorsementPremium]) AS DECIMAL(38,2)) 'Total Premium'
FROM
    [Data]
```

Comment: Check out the comments on the other answer

Comment: There are better ways to point out my mistake Erik. It was simply a misunderstanding. I misread his final CAST as a full equation. I thought the + was a * so in glancing, it looked like exactly what I was trying to avoid. Your tact in pointing out what I did wrong was very poor and very stereotypical of a forum poster. You mentioned site norms but clearly you don't feel it's important to stick with the other site norm of using decency above all else. I've posted several questions comments and you by far have shown the least bit of professionalism I've seen. Your tact alone will deter users.